# Email Acquisition Pop-up - How to Code?

Tags: web-development, node-js

For the past year and a half I have been building my own website. I am running everything through html, css, or javascript, but I realize that to accomplish some of my desired goals I need to create some features through another language.

I would like to create a form that pop's up (as a cookie) on viewers browser if they haven't signed up for my newsletter. All it will have is a name slot, and an email address. I also want it to be opt out, so if you fill the form in and click submit, you're opting in, if you click the "X" in the top right corner, you are opting out. TBH I don't even know where to start with this. I would love to work with some node.js, but I don't really have experience in it. Could anyone provide me a completed sample + a good resource for learning the language it is in? Thank you for much for the support.

Comment: You won't get a good answer from this forum since this is a place for basic issues with running a website in general, not for writing source code. You could try stackoverflow.com but if you post there, you should demonstrate all the steps you have tried to make your code work because questions that appear like homework questions get downvoted.